# I use semantic-release in GITLAB ,but the error is Invalid GitHub token.(Variable already been set)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, semantic-release

I already set the varaible,but it seems not work.

[image]

sementic log shows its was using @semantic-release/github,but actually my repo is in the gitlab, is that reason?By the way i have already install the @semantic-release/gitlab puglin

[semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/github"

other setting is here:

//.npmrc:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/

//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}

//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}
```

releaserc.json:

```
{
  "branches": ["master"],
  "plugins": [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    "@semantic-release/gitlab",
    "@semantic-release/npm",
    [
      "@semantic-release/git",
      {
        "assets": ["package.json"],
        "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version} [skip ci]\n\n${nextRelease.notes}"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that the `releaserc.json` you provided is in a different scope when you call `semantic-release`.

I base this on the fact you said in your question that semantic-release uses the `@semantic-release/github` plugin, which runs by default when no alternative configuration is provided to `semantic-release`.

You could try the following tutorial from GitLab to find where things turn south: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/semantic-release.html

Comment: So if releaserc file is in adifferent scope how can i fix it? I already read the tutorial but i found its gitlab-ci.yml example can't pass the cilint.

Comment: I assume you are trying to publish a NodeJS application to NPM. So if that is the case you could add a releaserc.json and npmrc to your project root and commit it to your repo. That way you don’t need to set it up in gitlab-ci. This should mitigate the problem that semantic-release can’t find your configuration.

Comment: I dont want to publish to npm... I just want the semanticrelease package to workwith gitlab

Answer (score 0):

In your quesstion you have specified the configuration file name as `releaserc.json` but it should be `.releaserc.json`.